# Use SVG from assets directory and place in xlink:href

Tags: angular, svg

Trying to take advantage of using the assets directory provided by angular, by using it to import svgs.

I want to import the svg file path into the xlink attribute such as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53066823/how-do-i-import-svg-from-file-to-a-component-in-angular-5).

```html
<svg>
  <use
    xlink:href="assets/img/logos/extant_logo_banner_favicon.svg"
  ></use>
</svg>
```

The result is that the svg isn't rendered and no errors are shown in the console. I inspected the svg that contains the use tag and it shows that the shadowroot under the use tag is empty.

I know that the path is correct because I tested an image element that uses that svg and it works

```html
<img src="assets/img/logos/extant_logo_banner_favicon.svg" alt="" />
```

I'm using angular 7.2.15