# Angular library img src

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-library

I am looking for a way to put images in the Angular Component Library. I mean img[src].
As for background-image, the library finds images from the assets folder, but if I try to attach images to img[src], it doesn't work. I also tried different src paths, absolute and relative.
I know the base64 way, but is there anything else?
I'm using Angular v12
and my ng-package.json looks like below:

```
  "assets": [
    "/assets/**/*",
    "/styles.scss",
    "/styles/**/*.scss"
  ]
```

In angular project below code works just fine:

```
<img src="/assets/img/foo.jpg">
```

but it does NOT work in angular library

Comment: Can you show an example of what isn't working? Just `<img src="/assets/img/foo.jpg">` should work. Square brackets in Angular (e.g `[src]`) are template expressions and will bind to a property, that's probably not what you want.

Comment: I'm sorry I could describe it a little bit better. Yes, indeed, your example works perfect in angular project, but it does NOT work in angular library

Comment: Ah, understood. I have no experience with Angular libraries, but maybe [this article](https://newbedev.com/include-assets-when-building-angular-library) is helpful?

Comment: Hi @Piosek, I've already answered your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64589400/11135174). But you have to export the assets to make them accessible from another project

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Include assets when building angular library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57741052/include-assets-when-building-angular-library)

Answer (score 0):

Your path to assets folder is not correct. Look your ng-package and assets folder of your library. It should be "assets": ["src/assets"].