# Angular library with multiple entry points lazy loading

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-module

I have a custom library with some custom element like: custom-a, custom-b and custom-c.
The structure is the following:

- projets/custom-lib

  - src/lib

    - custom-a

      - custom-a.component.ts
      - custom-a.component.scss.ts
      - custom-a.module.ts
    - custom-b

      - custom-b.component.ts
      - custom-b.component.scss.ts
      - custom-b.module.ts
    - custom-c

      - custom-c.component.ts
      - custom-c.component.scss.ts
      - custom-c.module.ts
- public-api.ts (includes those lines:

  ```
  export * from './lib/custom-a'
  export * from './lib/custom-b'
  export * from './lib/custom-c'
  ```

)

I'm using custom-b component in another app, by importing it on its app.module.ts.
I've noticed that unless adding custom-b in the app template (adding ),custom-b.component.scss content is not used/seen on browser. Why is that? Is there lazy loading for modules by default? (No routing is used)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add thef `custom-b` class (or maybe a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)) ? There is no lazy loading properly said, I would say that you did an error creating the custom-b component.

Comment: Adding a simplified stackblitz (without library, just some simple modules):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hkcgpv?file=src/app/app.component.html 
There are the main appModule which shows a p element with the class test-b, and three modules custom-a, custom-b, custom-c. Only when adding the app-custom-b element to the app component, we see custom-b styling being applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, so I think you did miss understand the way css works in angular. and are applying a css in an improper maner.

By telling that `ViewEncapsulation.None` you're removing the shadow DOM angular is generating. Which, when the components get rendered, will apply his css to every other element.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-b',
  templateUrl: './custom-b.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-b.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None, // <-- here
})
```

But this will only be applied when used.

A component, in Angular, should be able to leave on his own and should not impact other component (Not that way at least).

But if you wished to have a shared css file, you could do one of the following

### 1: Shared CSS

1. Create a new `shared.component.css` file
2. Add you css in there

```css
:host {
  .test-b {
    background-color: pink;
  }
}
```

3. Use it in the component you wish.

### 2 : Global CSS

1. Add global css in the `global_styles.css` file. this will change the `teat-b` in your entire project

### 3 : Import exported css in the `angular.json` file

1. Open the `angular.json` file
2. Add a new style to the `styles` array

```
"styles": [
"src/global_styles.css",
"new/path/to/my/project"
],
```

_[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57741052/include-assets-when-building-angular-library/64589400#64589400) if you don't know how to export CSS _

### Explanation: [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation)

#### None

Css will, when rendered, get applied to the entire project. prefer adding the component selector to avoid it having an impact in your project

```scss
app-custom-b {
  // your css
}
```

Pro: Let you change the css of some children element that you would be able to change otherwise.

Con: Not that good for optimization.

#### Encapsulated

Will be created in a kind of Shadow DOM.

Pro: Optimized

Con: You cannot change css in some children element that are in their own shadow DOM.